# 'Dass' instead of 'daß'

Tags: reformed-orthography

In the movie "Der Himmel über Berlin" the angel writes down a poem by Peter Handke (recent literature Nobel prize):

```
Als das Kind Kind war,
wusste es nicht,
dass es Kind war,
```

Why does the angel write 'dass' instead of 'daß'? This was 1987. The orthography reform was 1996. Was it common to write 'dass' previous to that?

Comment: Literary freedom?
Btw.: "ß" did never exits in Swiss German and "ß" was quite unpopular in some circles.

Answer (score 6):

The original text uses "ß":

> Als das Kind Kind war,
>
> wußte es nicht, daß es Kind war,

(Reference: https://handkeonline.onb.ac.at/node/1501 and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lied_vom_Kindsein )

I assume that they changed the "ß" to "ss" in the film for simplification or to make it more international. Using "ss" is a common thing to do, e.g. in forms (strasse instead of Straße) or in international correspondence with adresses and names.

Answer (score -1):

DUDEN regelt es so:

> Fehlt das ß (z. B. bei einem Computerprogramm), schreibt man dafür ss. In der Schweiz wird das ß generell durch ss ersetzt <§ 25 E2>.
>   ZUM BEISPIEL
>   Strasse (statt: Straße), aussen (statt: außen), Fussball (statt: Fußball)

[Quelle](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppel-s-und-scharfes-s)

Mit anderen Worten, du kannst ß oder ss schreiben bei egal welchem Wort und beides ist korrekt.

Comment: Nein, es ist nicht egal. Schreibt man Deutsch nicht in der Schweiz und ist nicht in der Tastatur eingeschränkt, muss man ß verwenden für die betreffenden Wörter.